# Updating Grid items in a List

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq

I have a list of `Grid` items called `gridCache`.
I have a `TabItem` called `ti`.

This line of code:

```
gridCache.Last().Name = ti.Name;
```

...is updating the `Name` property of every single `Grid` item in the list.  It should just be updating the last item's `Name` property.

Why is it doing this?

Maybe I'm rubberducking here, but I've followed it through a break point while debugging and they all just update simultaneously when this line is called.

EDIT:  I'd like to basically make 'copies' of `flyGrid` as it's modified to store them for later use.  The idea is to use this to cache data from some SQL calls.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
  //some stuff that defines flyGrid

  Grid cacheGrid = new Grid();
  cacheGrid = flyGrid;
  cacheGrid.Name = ti.Name;

  gridCache.Add(cacheGrid);
```

After this recurs 3 or 4 times, the `Name` property of every item in the list is always the last name supplied.

How can I make a copy of flyGrid that is its own instance each time this code recurs?

***SOLUTION EDIT***:
I ended up solving the root problem in a completely different way.  The idea was to get cached ReportParameterInfoCollection items to keep from talking to the database constantly.

I ended up creating a simple class for an object with two properties: one random string of letters, and a list of ReportParameterInfoCollection items.

This allowed me to populate this list as tabs are opened, and assign these tabs unique IDs that match the parameter information stored in this list of objects.

I didn't really *solve* the question, so I decided not to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

That would happen if every `Grid` is the same instance.

Make sure you're actually creating multiple instances when populating the list.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.  I'm using `gridCache.Add(flyGrid);`, where `flyGrid` is a Grid I've programmatically defined.  What's the quick and dirty to create a new instance of it before I chuck it into the List?

Comment: @SonnyChilds I believe what SLaks is saying is you need to declare a new Grid each time you add a grid to your gridCache list: `Grid flyGrid = new Grid(); gridCache.add(flyGrid);` making sure your not using the same instance over again: `Grid flyGrid = new Grid(); gridCache.add(flyGrid); flyGrid.Name = "thisName"; gridCache.add(flyGrid);`

Comment: Awesome, I see how to fix it now.  I had `flyGrid` defined in my XAML.  I'm going to create a new Grid object in the recursive function and get its properties from flyGrid before it goes into the List.  I'll post working code when done.

Comment: Okay, so not exactly working as anticipated.  Is there a way to take `flyGrid` and 'copy' it into a new instance of a grid and then store than into a list?  Updating main post now.

Comment: @SonnyChilds: You shouldn't be doing this at all.  Instead, you should use `ItemsSource` and a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: @SLaks This makes me very sad.  I feel like there should be an easy way to store a list of objects made from the same object and modify them separately.  I'm going to go find a dark corner to sulk in and then learn to use this `DataTemplate` wizardry. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @SonnyChilds: There is.  It's called `DataTemplate`, and it's much easier than manually consuming collections.  If you want to write clean, elegant, code in a framework, you need to learn how to use the framework, not fight it.  Data-binding is your friend.

Comment: @Slaks Gotcha, reading up on it now.  I'll try to stop struggling against the current.  I think it's that I'm more comfortable with C# than WPF.  This is actually my first WPF application and it's a pretty big undertaking of displaying SSRS reports in a tabbed layout with a Metro theme.  So far, it's coming out great, but I'm sure an experienced WPF programmer would be visibly taken aback at my disregard of the framework.